# Template parameter in std::function

Tags: c++, templates, std-function, template-argument-deduction

I have this piece of code and I do not understand why do not works.
During the compilation, in the lines where I call run(), I get:

```
Candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<double (const type-parameter-0-0 &, const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against 'double (*)(const data_t &, const data_t &)'
```

this is the code:

```
struct data_t {
  double value1;
  double value2;
};

double scoreValue1(const data_t & a, const data_t & b) { return a.value1 - b.value1; }
double scoreValue2(const data_t & a, const data_t & b) { return a.value2 * b.value2; }

template <class T>
void run(const std::vector<T> & dataA, const std::vector<T> & dataB, std::function<double(const T &, const T &)> function) {
  
  double value = 0;
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<dataA.size(); ++i)
    value += function(dataA[i], dataB[i]);
  
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  std::vector<data_t> dataA;
  std::vector<data_t> dataB;

  run(dataA, dataB, scoreValue1);
  run(dataA, dataB, scoreValue2);

  return 0;
  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Third argument to function `run` is declared to be `std::function<double(const T &, const T &)>`, however you pass a pointer to `scoreValue1` causing type deduction to be impossible. In order to deal with this problem you need to either

1. declare argument to be a pointer to function

```
void run
(
    const std::vector<T> & dataA
,   const std::vector<T> & dataB
,   double (* function )(const T & a, const T & b)
)
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAiFhkSwxcVK2mPYFDEIETMQEWT5%2BAXaYDhl1DQRFEdGxCbb1jc05XMM9fSVlEpIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm25UXgydAmJH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8cAbh1ExNe3D2bb52erzcTgUBGImFYP3uvzBxC8Dn26CY9QA%2BgRDgB2Kz3fZI5ZRej7N5iLyYLhHHF3PHoAlEkneTBmSm/EyYgAiLJh91pXkJLwUaAhADVSeSIGgGGCkSimOjDmYAGz7JikfaS6XItEY8zKqLzLEWfYQggrBgqgB0DLJXH2AFp9lErWKKZsjWzOTy6QKhZhRYyzBKBJrZfLdSq1RqMVq5TqlY6DWyjSazZbrUz9gAqR3OgOUrGeh73AiYFhJAwl4G7JgKBT7AAq0Lub1QeHQxrOvwgvzxeKj%2BzB6BAIA%2BDhIRzcjc22AVypjRbuar7wYxg%2BHo6%2BE6nM/DMapS/xfKJEGzp3ONX28yDUox9dnEfVK4b9/1v3mrOxPcOuMP/OJYtedl9g0LlqW/MD%2BGICA0gAL0weU8COdkQLdfZEOOecLVgzAIHfVDrGsPB3x/PF0wVKxNiAs8LgYCB5xMABWCxEIY9k1T3RjmMY9k8KpPEvzxNcUGWHVjgnf9GWBcShNcWhQN7cCPVZe5QgxFgmFCCBVJVYhgGQSMn2QBAGizHTgDeTjuMTT9uTAoSN3HDDQwIa4ZXqB43S/ezPkctwY3RVyOM82y8XhWj53Y2UbAHX1/RtXivzCujZUXNymGiwUSD9MUzASkLjUwU1iHNFC%2BMUjkOEWWhOAY3g/A4LRSFQTg3AIywB2WVYXi2HhSAITRKsWABrEAGI0fROEkOqBqazheAUEBxv6hrKtIOBYBgRBhLLOhYnISg0B2%2Bg4mALguACGhaBLYgFogKIZqiUIGgAT04XrDrYQQAHkGFoV6VtILB1KMcQAfwCFOg%2BBaAcwVQOi8Es3t4VSqhm2g8CiYgXo8LAZvBPAWCRxYqAMYAFGFPBMAAdy%2BpJGCRmRBBEMR2AqfhBEUFR1AB3QJgMIwUDamx0aiBbIEWVAkhqaG7UHJDTEsawzEa9oaJcBh3E8Fo9GCUJ%2BlKQYJjydIBDGPwjdSE2GGmAZykqaouhGJotfGe3PkdqY9ZmQ3JlGF3zd93ovdtiRFgUTq1j0cFMHWHgqpq6aAeajhVAADkVO1FUkfY9OQfYzotMx9ggVrFcsNVcEIEgFU2CZ9g8I7Yhrrh5l4ZatHmYbRvG6qOCm0hCbG0h6sa5P5sWvqBsWdatpEpIEf2oNG7tzB8C%2BPR2eEURxDZ2RObUPGIVj3gqaxpIiYmjhauHmbk6%2BhH54xVAqH2NOM6znPkDzgui5L1Bl%2Bbq3SeK1O6kAQJCLAcRcKX37oPcaI9eBj1sBPdug1SAjSHr3TYidR5zWAR3eOHAzA4MQXg1BoCPg3QyCASQQA%3D%3D%3D)

2. Put `T` of third argument into non-deducible context:

```
void run
(
    const std::vector<T> & dataA
,   const std::vector<T> & dataB
,   std::function<double(const ::std::type_identity_t<T> &, const ::std::type_identity_t<T> &)> function
)
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAiFhkSwxcVK2mPYFDEIETMQEWT5%2BAXaYDhl1DQRFEdGxCbb1jc05XMM9fSVlEpIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm25UXgydAmJH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8cAbh1ExNe3D2bb52erzcTgUBGImFYP3uvzBxC8Dn26CY9QA%2BgRDgB2Kz3fZI5ZRej7N5iLyYLhHHF3PHoAlEkneTBmSm/EyYgAiLJh91pXkJLwUaAhADVSeSIGgGGCkSimOjDmYAGz7JikfaS6XItEY8zKqLzLEWfYQggrBgqgB0DLJXH2AFp9lErWKKZsjWzOTy6QKhZhRYyzBKBJrZfLdSq1RqMVq5TqlY6DWyjSazZbrUz9gAqR3OgOUrGeh73AiYFhJAwl4G7JgKBT7AAq0Lub1QeHQxrOvwgvzxeKj%2BzB6BAIA%2BDhIRzcjc22AVypjRbuar7wYxg%2BHo6%2BE6nM/DMapS4HBCHIFO5xqE95/KDUoxw7XIAIAE8kphUW3GI4n%2Bit9dZ5GV/sd5HsOT4vm%2BWCCIQj7fsc26zvMv6nhcDC/AhMLYj2hy4vifL0mKrzsvsGhctSWGkfwxAQGkABer4YngRzssRbr7AxxzzhaNGYBACEsdY1h4GhpF4umCpWJshFITUEDziYACsFgMXJ7Jqnu8mKfJ7K8VSeKYXi95oF4OrHBOxL4ROpn3q4tAkb2ZEeqy9yhBiLBMKEEDOSqxDAMg/43uqCANFmXnAG86maYmGHcqR94buO7GhgQv6yW6mGxZ88VuDGMEzmpqXRXi8IMDJsqLjK9Q2AOvr%2Bja2mYUVJX1GVe5qoKJB%2BmKZh1QVxqYKaxDmsxOn2RyHCLLQnBybwfgcFopCoJwbj8ZYA7LKsLxbDwpAEJoY2LAA1iAckaPonCSNNu3zZwvAKCAJ07bNY2kHAsBIGgZZ0LE5CUO9SSfXEwBcFwAQ0LQJbELdEBRJdUShA0j6cFt71sIIADyDC0Ajj2kFgrlGOI2P4BCnQfLd2OYKoHRGesW3OVUl20HgUTEPDHhYJd4J4CwiNPVQBjAAowp4JgADuqMvjNW38IIIhiOwFTS/IShqJdugTAYRgoMtNiM1Et2QIsqBJDUZN2oOjGmJY1hmHN7TIS4DDuJ4LR6MEoT9KUgwTHk6QCGMfje6kvsMNMAzlJU1RdCMTTO%2BMEefFHUzuzMXuTKMscB2nvTJ2HEiLAoa1rHo4KYDTT0TRwU2kDNc0LRwqgAByKnaiqSPsPnIPsQMWmY%2BwQEtVuWGquCECQCqbBM%2BweB99DEOPXDzLwD1aPMB1HSdFfndXl11zdd3bbtq%2BnRwZgXdju8H49R8fBDGQgJIQA)

Comment: Importantly, each place `T` should be deduced is considered independantly, and there isn't a **unique** deduction of `T` for the function argument

Comment: 3. use explicit template param `run<data_t>(...)`. But 2 is the best imo.